# draw textfield caret and text selection onto bitmap

Tags: actionscript-3, bitmap, textfield, bitmapdata, caret

I'm drawing a textfield onto a bitmap which I use as texture for a 3D object. 
I'm listening for Event.change, and so whenever the user adds a character I redraw the texture. But to really give the 3D object a 'interactive textfield feeling', I want to draw text selections and draw the caret (the blinking text cursor), but by default these a not drawn when using bitmapData.draw(textField), nor can I find a Event to listen for 'textSelected'.

Any ideas?

```
//is there any event that catches text selection / blinking of text-cursor?
textField.addEventListener(Event.CHANGE, redrawTexture);
//...
//is there any way to draw text selection / text-cursor in the bitmap?
bmpData.draw(textField);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
textField.addEventListener(FocusEvent.FOCUS_IN, redrawTexture, false, 0, true);

textField.addEventListener(FocusEvent.FOCUS_OUT, redrawTexture, false, 0, true);

var bmp:BitmapData = new BitmapData(width, height);
bmp.draw(textField);
var snapshot:Bitmap = new Bitmap(bmp);
```